# How watch a variable from an external js file in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

English is not my primary language, sorry.

I'm working in a page with VueJs and Laravel, I have all the logic from a memory game in another js file locally (from a previous work, thats why is not in a vue component).

The problem is, I need to watch the remaining time and call a function when the timer is 0 to post the score in a database, but i couldn't make that work.

```
// game.js

// all other variables

export let timeRemaining = 30;
export let score = 0;

export function init() {
    startGame();
}
startGame(){...};
// all remaining logic ....
```

I tried calling the variables inside a ref, or inside a watch method, but nothing work for me.

```
// game.vue

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import * as game from '.game.js';

// first attempt (doesn't work)
const time = ref(game.timeRemaining);

onMounted(() => {
    game.init();
})

// second attempt (doesn't work)
watch(game.timeRemaining, (newTime) => {
    console.log(`time is ${newTime}`)
})
</script>
<template>
    <p>time: {{ time }}</p>
    // other stuff
</template>
```

The only solution I could find was modify the DOM directly

```
// game.js

// all other variables

export let timeRemaining = 30;
export let score = 0;
let showTime = null;

export function init() {
    showTime = document.getElementById("t-remaining");
    startGame();
}
startGame(){
    timerStart();
    // ...
};

function timerStart() {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        timeRemaining --;
        console.log(`Time: ${timeRemaining} remaining`);
        showTime.innerHTML = `Time: ${timeRemaining } remaining`;
        if (timeRemaining == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// all remaining logic ....
```

```
// game.vue

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import * as game from '.game.js';

// first attempt (doesn't work)
const time = ref(game.timeRemaining);

onMounted(() => {
    game.init();
})

// second attempt (doesn't work)
watch(game.timeRemaining, (newTime) => {
    console.log(`time is ${newTime}`)
})
</script>
<template>
    <h2 id="t-remaining">Time: 30</h2>
    // other stuff
</template>
```

This way the game work fine, but i need the timeRemaining and score variables in Vue because I need to send them to the laravel backend

Comment: Try to encapsulate the game logic in a composable function that uses reactivity api (ref,watch...) and the component lifecycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the logic inside `game.js` to a composable function named `useGame` :

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default function useGame() {
    let timeRemaining = ref(30);
    let score = ref(0);

    function startGame() {
        // Your game logic here...
    }

    function init() {
        startGame();
    }

    return { timeRemaining, score, init };
}
```

then use it inside the component :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import useGame from './useGame';

 const { timeRemaining, score, init } = useGame();

onMounted(() => {// you could also put this in the composable
    init();
})

watch(timeRemaining, (newTime) => {
    console.log(`time is ${newTime}`)
})
</script>
<template>
    <p>time: {{ timeRemaining }}</p>
    // other stuff
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, in the beginning doesn't work, but after change `timeRemaining--` to `timeRemaining.value--` works fine.